# Expected Calibration Error vs Cross-Entropy Loss

Tags: classification, metric

When would I use Expected Calibration Error over Cross Entropy Loss. I think I understand when to use Cross Entropy Loss i.e. it is easy to optimize Cross Entropy Loss during training. But can I not just use Cross Entropy Loss where ever I would use Expected Calibration Error?